# Getting DropletException while creating handleMethod

Tags: atg

I'm trying to create own handle method for registration form. It has only two fields first name and last name. Below is the sample java code.

```
public class TestProfileFormHandler extends GenericFormHandler{

protected ProfileTools mProfileTools;
private MutableRepository mSampleRepository;
private String mCreateSuccessURL;
private String mCreateErrorURL;
public static final String FIRST_NAME = "firstName";
public static final String LAST_NAME = "lastName";

public boolean handleCreate(DynamoHttpServletRequest pRequest,DynamoHttpServletResponse pResponse)throws ServletException,IOException{

    MutableRepository lSampleRepository = (MutableRepository) getSampleRepository();
    MutableRepositoryItem lItem = null;
    String lFirstName = pRequest.getParameter(FIRST_NAME);
    String lLastName = pRequest.getParameter(LAST_NAME);
    try {
        Repository rep = getSampleRepository();
        RepositoryItem lRepoItem = null;

        lItem = lSampleRepository.createItem(lRepoItem.getRepositoryId(),"user");
        lItem.setPropertyValue(FIRST_NAME,lFirstName);
        lItem.setPropertyValue(LAST_NAME, lLastName);
        String lRepositoryId = lItem.getRepositoryId();
        lSampleRepository.addItem(lItem);
    } catch (RepositoryException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return checkFormRedirect(getCreateSuccessURL(), getCreateErrorURL(), pRequest, pResponse);

}
```

Below is the jsp : register.jsp

```
<dsp:page>
<dsp:importbean bean="/atg/userprofiling/TestProfileFormHandler"/>
<dsp:getvalueof id="success" param="added"/>
<c:if test="${success eq true}">
    Account created successfully.
</c:if>
<dsp:form name="registerForm" id="registerForm" method="post">
    <div>
        <label>First Name</label> <span>*: </span>
        <dsp:input type="text" name="firstName" bean="TestProfileFormHandler.value.firstName" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Last Name</label> <span>*: </span>
        <dsp:input type="text" name="lastName" bean="TestProfileFormHandler.value.lastName" />
    </div>
    <dsp:input type="hidden" value="/test/register.jsp?added=true" bean="TestProfileFormHandler.createSuccessURL"/>
    <dsp:input type="hidden" value="/test/register.jsp?added=false" bean="TestProfileFormHandler.createErrorURL"/>
    <dsp:input type="submit" value="Create Account" bean="TestProfileFormHandler.create"/>
</dsp:form>
```

now i'm getting `DropletException`

```
atg.droplet.DropletException: Can't find property: firstName in class com.tap.userprofiling.TestProfileFormHandler
at atg.droplet.DropletDescriptor.<init>(DropletDescriptor.java:813)
at atg.droplet.validation.ValidatingDropletDescriptorManager$ValidationDropletDescriptor.<init>(ValidatingDropletDescriptorManager.java:416)
at atg.droplet.validation.ValidatingDropletDescriptorManager.createDropletDescriptor(ValidatingDropletDescriptorManager.java:219)
at atg.droplet.DropletDescriptorManager.getDropletDescriptor(DropletDescriptorManager.java:1279)
at atg.droplet.DropletDescriptorManager.getDropletDescriptor(DropletDescriptorManager.java:1232)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

if anyone knows what's this error, please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you not using the OOTB ProfileFormHandler which has all of this functionality already built in.  Seems like you are wasting a lot of time reinventing the wheel!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues I can see here. Firstly you are trying to use a 'value' map for transferring your property values between your JSP page and your `formhandler` but you don't have a `value` property defined in your `formhandler` nor does it have any accessors. If you were extending the out-of-the-box `ProfileFormHandler` it would have given you access to the `value` dictionary, but be careful as some of the elements in the dictionary gets used explicitly.

Coupled to the above you are essentially doing a `POST` on `TestFormHandler.value.firstName` but simply trying to read `firstName` from the request. There is no `firstName` on the request which probably results in your error.

Another issue is that you shouldn't set property values in a `FormHandler` using the `request` object. You should do this via accessors on the individual properties instead. (Best Practice).

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, Instead of using value dictionary i just created variable firstName and lastName in java file and created setter and getters. This method worked fine for my code.

Comment: Now, DropletException issue has been resolved but data is not setting in  database. Item is creating but i can't see it nowhere.